# problem in send request to fedex tracking api integration

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

when we send request to fedex at the time of fedex integration then we get an error that is

> Code:HTTP String:Unable to parse URL.

in php codeigniter

so how we solve this error?

Comment: you should place your code here.

Comment: It should be some issue related with the URL. Sample code is necessary to find it out in detail.